# Wanted: A C# serialization library that is independent of the serialization format

Tags: c#, serialization

What I am looking for is an open source serialization library that is generic and extensible.

It should support the extension of type / property attributes and the configuration of the encoders, so that the whole range from binary serialization to text based serialization could be implemented based on it.

Is there something similar?

Comment: lol, sure, SO, github, google, duckduck go, asked via twitter, etc.

Comment: Always have to ask though ;) Some people...

Answer (score 0):

try to use protocol buffer for your purpose http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that protocol buffers were independent of the serialization format. I am taking a look at the C# port right now.

Comment: I can't see how the serialization format can be customized in protocol buffers. Any ideas?

Comment: it's open sourse and you can add own behavior

Comment: Sure that's an option, but a tedious one.